# What is the difference between "leading" and "winning" in a game?

Tags: grammaticality, differences

Is it correct to use 'winning' or 'leading' when referring to the current state of a match/game?

e.g. for a game between Patriots and Broncos in progress, if Patriots have scored higher points than Broncos, would it be correct to say that "Patriots are winning" or that "Patriots are leading"?

Comment: Either one works. Might be different for sports like golf where getting more points is a bad thing?

Comment: I want to say _"The two can often be used synonymously, but it might vary depending on which game you play."_ but I can't think of a single example of a competitive game or sport where they can't be used interchangeably.

Comment: On the other hand, when used in connection with the run-up to an election, "leading in the polls" is (arguably) meaningful, since the poll measures current popularity; but "winning in the polls" is nonsensical: You win the election at the ballot box, not in the opinion polls.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your response.  My friend and I have been arguing about the correct usage and these responses provide reasonable arguments.

Comment: You would say your favorite team is "winning", but you would likely say that the other team is only "leading".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take **winning** to express an expectation in the speaker that the current scores would lead them to win.

I take **leading** to mean up in score but not necessarily in a way that implies winning.

To give a somewhat clear (though perhaps not if you don't understand American football scoring example), If one team (Team A) has 7 points and the other team (Team B) had zero points but has just scored a touchdown, then the score would 7-6, then Team A would be *leading* but not winning -- as the extra point is scored with such high frequency, that most observers would not imagine Team A as having any real advantage even though they are leading on the scoreboard.

Comment: If I might give an alternative example, a chess player who has sacrificed his queen to get an overwhelmingly advantageous position is not 'leading' (since he has fewer pieces) but is 'winning'.

Answer (score 2):

In any game with a fixed time duration, leading in the earliest part of the game can say little about whether a competitor is winning.

This can also be illustrated when the leader is the only one that has had an opportunity to score, or the leading team is about to turn over its scoring privilege and thereby give the opponent a chance to overturn the score. This can happen in baseball, where the teams may be close in score and the leading team goes to the outfield in the top of the ninth inning.

Another example occurs in a relay race, where the anchor runner (the last runner) on a team is known to be especially good and likely to overturn race.

In an election, ballot counting may show a bias toward one candidate in the early counts, showing that candidate is leading. But knowing something about the uncounted precincts can lead a knowledgable poll watcher to know that leading is not necessarily winning.

In cases like these, leading does not necessarily equate to winning.

Answer (score 2):

Leading, to me, is what's happening at a certain time in the game when people are still uncertain of who is going to win. 
 Winning is more towards the end of the game, or at least to a point when people are certain that a particular party/team is going to win.
 That's the way I think about it.

Answer (score 1):

In the context you mention the correct word would be leading.

There is the concept of "winning". It's a nominalization of the verb "to win". It implies the outcome of a match.

There is the verb "winning". It denotes the verb "to win", performed intransitively in the moment. Thus, for the patriots to be winning, one must:

1. Be certain of the outcome
2. Be describing the Patriots in the act of winning, in the current moment

The word leading, however, implies a temporary action, applied transitively. Thus the patriots cab be leading the Packers 7-0.

So, if you were narrating an NFL Films documentary about the Super Bowl 31, you could use the word "winning". But if you were a sports caster narrating the live game you would have to use the verb "leading".

Answer (score 1):

Leading applies during the game and winning comes only toward the end, unless one is guessing the outcome of the match.